# exim reject all local_part matching a pattern

Tags: exim, mail-transport-agent

I am trying to configure Exim to reject any `$local_part` that match a pattern.

For example, I know that none of the local_parts for any of the myriad of domains I host will ever contains numbers.  So, I know if someone send an email to `fubar1235434@domain.tld`, I know it is spam and can safely reject it.

What would be the best ACL for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ACL line could be the next:

```
deny condition = ${lookup{$localpart}nwildlsearch{/path/to/the/black.list}{yes}{no}}
```

While `black.list` contains PCRE regexes one per line like that:

```
^.*[0-9].*
^.*[!@#$%^&*()_+].*
^.*sales.*
```

Comment: If other solution allows to modify regex list without `exim`'s restart - let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Based off [Kondybas](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/32544/kondybas)'s [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/160371/10526), an Ubuntu/Debian specific answer is to change the follow lines in `/etc/exim4/conf.d/main/01_exim4-config_listmacrosdefs` to read:

```
.ifndef CHECK_RCPT_LOCAL_LOCALPARTS                                             
CHECK_RCPT_LOCAL_LOCALPARTS = ^[.] : ^.*[@%!/|`#&?0-9]                          
.endif
```

Clearly this only works for adding `[0-9]` to the pattern. Other patterns might require [Kondybas](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/32544/kondybas)'s [solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/160371/10526).